# Swipe an item in listView along finger

Tags: android, listview, swipe

I want to swipe an item in `ExpandablelistView` and push it offscreen. I can do it now, but this action performs when my swipe gesture ends and **I want it move exactly with my finger** like gmail new app when you swipe an email. (I also like to have the transparency as translation increases)
Could you please help me with giving some advice or tutorial link?

I have an adapter that extends `BaseExpandableAdapter`, a class for detecting swipe gesture and a `mainActivity`

MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnScrollListener{
    ExpandableListView lv1;
    private CustomListAdapter cla;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv1 = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        final SwipeDetector swipeDetector = new SwipeDetector();
        lv1.setOnTouchListener(swipeDetector);
        cla = new CustomListAdapter(this);
        addData();
        lv1.setAdapter(cla);
        lv1.setOnScrollListener(this);
        lv1.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                Object o = cla.getGroup(groupPosition);
                MatchResult m =((trnmSeparator) o).getMatches().get(childPosition);
                //int type = (Integer) rowType.get(position);
                if (swipeDetector.swipeDetected()){
                    // do the onSwipe action
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SWIPE :" + " " + m , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    float dest = 0;
                    v = v.findViewById(R.id.match);
                    float place = v.getX();
                    if (swipeDetector.getAction() == Action.LR){
                        if (place == 0) dest =  v.getWidth();
                        else if (place > 0) dest = v.getWidth();
                        else if (place < 0) dest = 0;
                    } 
                    else if (swipeDetector.getAction() == Action.RL){
                        if (place == 0) dest =  -v.getWidth();
                        else if (place > 0) dest = 0;
                        else if (place < 0) dest = -v.getWidth();
                    } 
                    ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "x", dest);
                    oa.setDuration(700);
                    oa.start();
                    Log.v("view type", v.toString());
                    return false;
                } else {
                    // do the onItemClick action
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected :" + " " + m, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });

        lv1.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                if (swipeDetector.swipeDetected()){
                    // do the onSwipe action
                    Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(groupPosition);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SWIPE :" + " " + o , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
                if (lv1.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)){
                    Object o = cla.getGroup(groupPosition);
                    Log.v("type", o.getClass().toString());
                    for (int i = 0; i < ((trnmSeparator) o).getMatches().size(); i++){
                        lv1.getChildAt(i).setX(0f);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        lv1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Long Press" + lv1.getItemAtPosition(arg2), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean loadMore = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount;  //maybe add a padding 
        if(loadMore) {
            addData();
            //cla.count += visibleItemCount; // or any other amount
            cla.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

and my swipe detector

```
package com.example.jadidtar;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class SwipeDetector implements View.OnTouchListener {
    public static enum Action {
        LR, // Left to Right
        RL, // Right to Left
        None // when no action was detected
    }

    private static final String logTag = "SwipeDetector";
    private static final int HORIZONTAL_MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
    private float downX, downY, upX, upY;
    private Action mSwipeDetected = Action.None;

    public boolean swipeDetected() {
        return mSwipeDetected != Action.None;
    }

    public Action getAction() {
        return mSwipeDetected;
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                downX = event.getX();
                downY = event.getY();
                mSwipeDetected = Action.None;
                return false; // allow other events like Click to be processed
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                upX = event.getX();
                upY = event.getY();

                float deltaX = downX - upX;
                float deltaY = downY - upY;

                // horizontal swipe detection
                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > HORIZONTAL_MIN_DISTANCE) {
                    // left or right
                    if (deltaX < 0) {
                        mSwipeDetected = Action.LR;
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (deltaX > 0) {
                        mSwipeDetected = Action.RL;
                        return true;
                    }
                } 
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a part of code that im using to do the same as you want. It use `onTouchListner` on  (linearLayout) object (wich is my listview row)  :

```
VelocityTracker _VelocityTracker;
int _slop; 

ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(context);
_slop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();

 [.........code ......]

_dividerRow.setOnTouchListener(new MyGestureListener()
                );


class MyGestureListener implements OnTouchListener{
        private PointF _init;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch(event.getAction())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                _init = new PointF(event.getRawX(), event.getRawY());
                if(!(v == null))
                {
                    _VelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                    _VelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
                }

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
                if(event.getX() > 0)
                {
                        _VelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
                        float diffX = event.getRawX() - _init.x;
                        float diffY = event.getRawY() - _init.y;

                        if (Math.abs(diffX) > _slop && Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                            _swipping = true;
                            ((ViewGroup) v).requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                            MotionEvent cancelEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(event);
                            cancelEvent.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL | (event.getActionIndex() << MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT));
                            v.onTouchEvent(cancelEvent);
                        } 

                        if(_swipping == true)
                        {

                            ViewHelper.setTranslationX(v, diffX);
                        }
                    }

                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank for your answer. Would you please explain your code and your variables? (like _slop, leave, etc)

Comment: Sorry, leave was an old condition, I deleted it. For the rest : im updating my previous post

Comment: I used your code but now my app doesn't responds to any touch event!